# EM for conditional Gaussian model

Tags: statistics, optimization, normal-distribution, parameter-estimation

Let $$X_1\sim N(\mu_{X_1},\sigma_{X_2}^2)$$ $$X_2\sim N(\mu_{X_2},
\sigma_{X_2}^2)$$
where $\mu_{X_2}=c+aX_1$. Also, I have data $D$ (with missing values on $X_1,X_2$).

How can I update/estimate the parameters $\mu_{X_1},\sigma_{X_1},\mu_{X_2},a,c,\sigma_{X_2}$ using EM? i.e. what is the formula for updating $\sigma_{X_2}$?

My model is a conditional Gaussian, which is a conditional form of a bivariate Gaussian $(X_1,X_2)$ with mean vector $(\mu_1,\mu_2)^\top$ and covariance matrix 
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   \Sigma _{11} & \Sigma _{12}  \\
   \Sigma _{21} & \Sigma _{22}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$

Here is a reference to convert bivariate Gaussian to conditional Gaussian: $$\mu_{2|1}=\mu_{2}+\Sigma_{21}\Sigma_{11}^{-1}(X_1-\mu_1)\quad,\quad \Sigma_{22|1}=\Sigma_{22}-\Sigma_{21}\Sigma_{11}^{-1}\Sigma_{12}$$ which yields my model.

It seems that when $X_1$ has different observations and $X_2$ is unobserved, the variance of $X_2$ remains unchanged.So how to update the $\sigma_{x_2}$? Do I need to estimate covariance matrix?

Initial setting for the model
$$X_1\sim N(5,7)\quad,\quad X_2\sim N(0.5X_1,8)$$

**Data:**

$$X_1:\operatorname{9\,\,4\,\,NA}$$

$$\quad X_2:\operatorname{NA\,\,NA\,\,3}$$

Comment: Your model is not clear. You may need to describe your data and provide more details on your model.

Comment: revised as required.

Comment: This is still not clear, and you have too less data.

Comment: This may be migrated to "Cross Validated".

Comment: do you know Kalman filter ?

Comment: this model will be able to run in Matlab BNT tool box. But I dont know what formula it uses in estimating the covariance matrix.

Comment: I suggest migrating this to Cross Validated. It seems to be 100% statistics/algorithm and 0% finance (even though it could be applied in finance).

Comment: Hi all, I post this question here because I did not get an answer from cross-validation, which was disappointed. I was disappointed not only because there is no answer, but also because they simply turn my question into similar issues without actually examining the problem. There is huge difference actually between different issues. Also, I post my question here because I think at here, there are many quants/statisticians who are more responding than there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $X_1$ is unobserved, at iteration $k=1$ of EM, the posterior mean value (when $X_2=3$) is $5.18$ by using an inference algorithm, i.e. Junction tree/Kalman filter. 
Then the sufficient statistics for $X_1$ is:

$s_1=\Sigma_{i=1}^nx_{i1}=9+4+5.18$ and $s_{11}=\Sigma_{i=1}^nx_{i1}^2=9^2+4^2+(5.18^2+\sigma_{11.2})$

where $\sigma_{11.2}$ is the posterior conditional variance of $X_1$ given $X_2$, when $X_1$ is unobserved.

$s_2=\Sigma_{i=1}^nx_{i2}$ and $s_{22}=\Sigma_{i=1}^nx_{i2}^2$. When $X_2$ is unobserved a term $\sigma_{22.1}$ is also added to $x_{i2}^2$.

So parameters $\mu_{X_1}$ and $\sigma_{X_1}$ are obtained. Similarly, posterior mean of unobserved $X_2$ is also obtained by using i.e. Junction tree inference.

The sufficient statistics for $s_{12}=\Sigma_{i=1}^nx_{i1}x_{i2}$, and $s_{21}=\Sigma_{i=1}^nx_{i2}x_{i1}$.

Mean vector is then: $\mu^{(k)}=(s_1/n, s_2/n)$.

Covariance matrix is: $\Sigma^{(k)}=$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   \Sigma _{11} & \Sigma _{12}  \\
   \Sigma _{21} & \Sigma _{22}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$=$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   s_{11}/n-(s_1/n)^2 & s_{21}/n-(s_2/n)(s_1/n)  \\
   s_{12}/n-(s_1/n)(s_2/n) & s_{22}/n-(s_2/n)^2  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$
 $

Other parameters in the question are obtained. Conditional mean and conditional variance of $X_2|X_1$ is calculated by the formula in the reference of the question.
I have validated these formulae with Matlab the result is correct.